# Error when Importing Entities created in JDL-Studio: "Could not find jhipster-jdl.jh, make sure the path is correct"

Tags: jhipster

As the title says, I´m trying to import a jh file generated by JDL-Studio and it´s giving me that error.

My file name is jhipster-jdl.jh and im using the command "jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh"

```
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! Executing import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh
INFO! Options: from-cli: true

Could not find jhipster-jdl.jh, make sure the path is correct.
```

First it says it´s executing the import, but then it says it couldn´t find the file. Does this seem normal? I honestly don´t know where I´m supposed to put the downloaded file, but I have it inside the proyect folder, and i´m also executing the command on the proyect folder too.

Comment: If you run `ls` from the same directory you run `jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh`, is `jhipster-jdl.jh` listed?

Comment: Nope, only "myApp" which is the proyect i´m working.I jhipster-jdl.jh is not listed because i put it inside "myApp". Should i put it outside?

Comment: The argument you pass to `import-jdl` is the path to the JDL file.  If you are trying to import the JDL into `myApp`, run it from the root of that folder.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you pass to `import-jdl` is the path to the JDL file. If you are trying to import the JDL into a generated JHipster app `myApp`, run it from the root of that folder.